# how to vectorize a function whose argument is a vector in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have an numpy array `R` of dimension (n, n, n, 3) and a function `f` which takes a 1-D vector to a scalar. I need a new array `A` whose relationship with `R` is

```
A[i, j, k] = f(R[i, j, k, :])
```

How can I do this in numpy without three for statements.

Comment: This depends on what `f` is. Hopefully, it'll be as simple as adding `axis` arguments in a few places.

Comment: `f` is so complicated that I don't even want to post it here.

Comment: Anther 'trick' is to reshape `R` to 2d, so you index on just one axis, and slice the other.  Then reshape the result back.  In other words, temporarily 'flatten' the `i,j,k` dimensions.  It won't save iteration steps, but should simplify the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you'd do this by changing the implementation of `f` to use techniques that handle high-dimensional input appropriately. For example, you might change `np.sum(whatever)` to `np.sum(whatever, axis=-1)` to get a sum over the last axis instead of the whole array. This would produce the most efficient results, but it might be difficult or impossible, depending on `f`.

The slower, much easier answer is [`np.apply_along_axis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
A = np.apply_along_axis(f, -1, R)
```

This is prettier than 3 for loops, but it probably won't be any more efficient.

Comment: Is `np.vectorize` more efficient than for loops?

Comment: Plus `vectorize` is tricky to apply when the function takes a 1d array instead of a scalar.